# Netsend GUI tool for send and receive netsend message for `ubuntu 15.04`

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, samba4

Im looking for http://www.winsentmessenger.com/ kind of tool that can both send and receive netsend messages.. Only im using Ubuntu/lubuntu and the other users use widnows 7/8/8.1 pcs on the local network...(Not sure samba client can receive netsend messages sent by windows pcs though it can send messages out `smbclient -M`)

I tried using wine and winsent but its not working.. and checked https://superuser.com/questions/105306/way-to-do-netsend-between-a-windows-and-ubuntu-computer .

Not sure how to install [linpopup (Last modified 2007-09-09)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linpopup2/files/) or  [LinWinTalk (Last Update: 2013-03-12)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gladenetsend/)

I found this guide for linpopup  http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/unofficial_ubuntu_starter_guide/index_022.html yet in section "How to add extra repositories" im seeing `Ubuntu 5.04 (Hoary)` repos.. Seems pretty obsolete .. yet i could not find any such guide for LinWinTalk

Please share, any tips for **working gui tool** or working Compile guide/installation guide for send and receive netsend message for **`ubuntu 15.04`**

Answer (score 1):

This will not answer your question but answer your problem:

You can use instead :

- *beebeep*: http://beebeep.sourceforge.net/ (multi-platform with a GUI)
- *tox*: https://tox.im/ (skype like but encrypted and you can make your own node, multi-platform)
- or you can setup an irc server and use regular IRC client.

BUT this means changing the other clients on the LAN too.